# Required_if with data type - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to validate name & status.

If `status = 1` it should validate name else it should skip validation of `name`.
When I send `status = 0` it says:

> name must be a string

But it should skip validation of name as per conditional validation.

When I send `status=1` then it works as intended.

```
'status' => 'required|numeric',
'name' => 'required_if:status,1|string'
```

What needs to be corrected here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do resolve this:

```
public function rules()
{
   $rules = [
       'status' => ['required', 'numeric'],
       'name' => ['string'],
   ];

   if ($this->status == '1') {
       array_push($rules['name'], 'required');
   }

   return $rules;
}
```